# Rails 6 multiple databases and query timeout problems when running db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-replication, ruby-on-rails-6

On `MyModel` I use configuration which enables db replication to work

```
connects_to database: { writing: :primary, reading: :follower }
```

In some migrations there are queries like:

```
MyModel.update_all(...)
```

And they result with:

```
PG::QueryCanceled: ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
```

If I remove `connects_to database: { writing: :primary, reading: :follower }` I am not getting this error anymore which somehow proves that replication setup is responsible for this error in migration file.

I know I could start fixing all migrations but I would rather not do this ..

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that Rails was using multiple connections to the database and they were creating deadlocks to each other.

This was happening because some models were properly extending ApplicationRecord (where reading/writing role should be defined!) however some of them were extending ActiveRecord::Base which led to opening up more connections than needed.

One of my attempt was also creating abstract class ApplicationRecordWithReplication which I used for models where replication was needed. This again resulted with more DB connections than needed.